# yumでインストールしたPHP7.0を7.1へアップグレードしたい

Tags: php, centos, yum

**環境**
・CentOS7
・yumでインストールしたPHP7.0

---

**質問**
・7.1へアップグレードするには？

---

**案1.yum update php --enablerepo=remi-php71**
・上記は何をするコマンド？
・php71のリポジトリを指定してyum updateするので、PHP7.1へアップグレードされる？

**案2.yum install --enablerepo=remi-php71 php**
・PHP7.0が動作している状態で、php71のリポジトリを指定してインストールしたら、PHP7.1へアップグレードされる？

**案3.yum remove php-*した後、案2**
・最初に既存のPHPは削除が必要ですか？

Comment: ここが、参考になるかと、
https://qiita.com/bezeklik/items/860ba080bf4c664cd8e9

Comment: 既存のphp-7.0はどのリポジトリからインストールしたものでしょうか(標準リポジトリはphp-5.4のはず)。

Comment: @cubik。remiリポジトリからインストールしました「--enablerepo=remi-php70」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下はCentOS 6で確認した結果です。

baseリポジトリ、もしくはremi-php70リポジトリからphpを既にインストールした状態で
`yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php`を実行した場合には、既存のパッケージを置き換える形で
**上書きインストール**されました(`install`の代わりに`upgrade`指定でも同様)。
事前の削除は特に必要ないと思います。
`-y`オプションを使わない限り、インストール・アップグレード前に簡単なサマリーが表示されるので何が起きるのかは事前に確認ができるかと。

`--enablerepo`オプションは`/etc/yum.repo.d/*.repo`で普段無効にされているリポジトリをコマンドラインから一時的に有効にするオプションです。`man yum`でオプションを確認しましょう。

Comment: 確認いただきありがとうございました。大変参考になりました